# Entity Framework Core 3.1 - Oracle “Specified cast is not valid”

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my .NET Core 3.1 application I am using linq to get a list of entries from a view using the following statement:

```
List<VEntries> entryList = dbContext.VEntries.Where(x => x.Timestamp.HasValue && 
                                            x.Timestamp.Value.Date == dateTimeLocal.Date && 
                                            x.Timestamp.Value.Hour == dateTimeLocal.Hour)
                                .ToList();
```

`dateTimeLocal` in this case equals the timestamp to search entries for in local time.

This code works fine in my local environment but on the production system it throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
> at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

The database view is identical on both systems and contains a column `Timestamp` of type `DATE` which is nullable:
[image]

The generated model looks like this:

```
public partial class VEntries
{
    public string QualityData { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public decimal? Average { get; set; }
    public decimal? Min { get; set; }
    public decimal? Max { get; set; }
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Could you post the code for `entryData` and also the configuration for the entity/view involved?

Comment: @dglozano entryData is simply dbContext.VEntries. I modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you posted, I believe the error is not related to the `DateTime` field, but with the `decimal` ones instead:

`at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)`

Oracle's `NUMBER` range is bigger than C# `decimal`, so it is probably not managing to convert one very large number read in the production database into your application. I bet that locally is working because in your local database you don't have any number as big.

Possible solutions:

1. Truncate or round decimals in your production database (if it is an option).
2. If the first alternative isn't possible, you could try adding a `ValueConverter` for your decimal values in `VEntries` that converts from a `double` (less precision but bigger range) to `decimal`(more precision, less range) and vice-versa.

I haven't tried it, but should look something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<VEntries>()
        .Property(e => e. Value)
        .HasConversion(
            decimalValue => (double)decimalValue,
            doubleValue => (decimal)doubleValue);
       // Repeat for all decimal values
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what caused the error in the production environment. I think it is quite a pitfall though that the oracle data provider does not take this into account.

Comment: @Chris glad you managed to solve it  yes, it sucks.. but I guess it probably idoesn't want to silently truncate your numbers in case it affects your calculations. Btw, just wondering, did you go for option 1 or 2?

Comment: Option 1 because we have access to the production database and could therefore just round the decimals in the view.