# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC : Integer conversion between .net and oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project, using `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` (tried all 3 latest version) to build code from an existing Oracle database.

EF Core provides the database first method to create models from the database tables.

In the Oracle database, the Book table has definition of

```
BOOK_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
```

And EF Core created the field as int32

```
public int BookId { get; set; }
```

In the `BooksController`, `GetBook` method, there is this line:

```
var Book = await _context.Books.FindAsync(id);
```

When the id is small, for example, 5, it worked just fine. However when the id is big, for example, 412897, it will throw an error. The entire error stack trace by Postman is pasted below:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt16(Int32 i)
> at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext
> , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1
> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at MyProject.Controllers.BookController.GetBook(Int32 id) in C:\repos\Books\Books\Controllers\BookController.cs:line 35    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> HEADERS
> ======= Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Connection: keep-alive Host: localhost:44324 User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
> Postman-Token: e07b32ea-c4aa-4c29-9edf-51eb0581dfe8

By searching online it seems to be the different definitions of integer by .net and Oracle. I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690780/entity-framework-core-3-1-oracle-specified-cast-is-not-valid) to add `HasConversion` to `OnModelCreating` in `DbContext` class.

```
entity.Property(e => e.BookId)
                    .HasPrecision(10)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasColumnName("Book_ID")
                    .HasConversion(t => Convert.ToInt32(t), t => Convert.ToInt32(t));
```

However it doesn't solve the problem. The error was as before.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out the last comment at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4293559/using-number-5-in-db-with-ef-core-2-2

Comment: `GetInt16` indicates that for some reason the column is mapped as `Int16` (`short`). Which provider version from these https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/ are you using? And is there any data annotation/fluent configuration of the property id in question not shown here?

Comment: @IvanStoev I have tried the 3 latest version of oracle ef core. All started from scratch to create the models, dbcontext and controller. All resulted in the same error.

Comment: Ok. This `GetInt16` is the problem, we need to figure out why is that (the expected is `GetInt32`) and how to avoid it (value converter Int32 to Int32 does nothing and won't help). Can you post the whole exception stack trace?

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev I have pasted the whole exception stack trace. The format is kind of messed up. If you need I can send it to you.

Comment: @mjwills Hi I have read the post, it seems to me it works on the creating of the table. However we have the tables created in the database. Applying table creation from ef resulted in an error.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't show anything useful. I start having a feeling that the error is for some other column than `BookId`. Could you please try the following `var test = _context.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == id).Select(x => x.BookId).ToList();` with id 412897 and see if it succeeds or fails with the same error?

Comment: @IvanStoev Your query worked. It returned a list with one element "412897".

Comment: Ok, now you have to find the actual field which is failing. Look at the class for a property of type `short` (or `Int16`). And make it `int`. Or start adding fields one by one to the `Select` of my query (e.g. `Select(x => new { x.BookId, x.SecondField, ...})`) until you get an error.  Then correct the last added field.

Comment: @IvanStoev Let me try that, thank you a lot.